# CollapsingToolbarLayout in viewpager

Tags: android, material-design

This is my main activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvFeed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/view_feed_toolbar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btn_fab_margins"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btn_fab_margins"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_instagram_white"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is one of my tabs fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvFeed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so what is happening is that my map View is stick under the tabs.i want to use CollapsingToolbarLayout or just scroll with my RecyclerView.
how to use it?i have already set my tab layout in my main activity XML...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your fragment's layout as such

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
       </LinearLayout>
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/rvFeed"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
          android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: my RecyclerView just gone in that way and dont know why.my adapter for this works fine without NestedScrollView.